# Standalone + Pstricks

Tags: pstricks, compiling, standalone

I'm trying to compile the following MWE using TeXniCenter and

- latex -> ps -> pdf (ghostscript)
- latex -> dvi -> pdf (dvips + ghostscript)
- latex -> dvi -> pdf (dvips + ps2pdf)

None of these ways is working, I just get an empty page. Afterwards, I would like to create multiple pages using standalone + pstricks + multido. Can somebody help?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[PointSymbol=none](4,6)
\pstGeonode[PointName=
{V,none},PosAngle=->135,CurveType=polygon,linecolor=red]{A}(4,0){B}(4,6){C}
\pstMarkAngle[arrows=->,MarkAngleRadius=4]{B}{A}{C}{$\theta$}
\pcline[offset=-8pt,linecolor=red]{|*-|*}(A)(B)\ncput*{1}
\ncline[linestyle=none]{A}{C}\naput[nrot=:U]{$\sec \theta$}
\ncline[linestyle=none]{C}{B}\naput[nrot=:U]{$\tan \theta$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Loading `auto-pst-pdf`, you can compile directly with `pdflatex`.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?77137-standalone-pstricks&p=362329&viewfull=1#post362329)

Comment: Not working for me ... Adding "\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}" and compiling with pdflatex leads to this error: "LaTeX error: \begin{pspicture} on input line 5 ended by \end{document}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in the code: `sAngle=->135` should be  `PosAngle=-135`.

[image]